# How to log JPA/SQL queries with JavaMelody?

Tags: java, jpa, persistence.xml, java-melody

I have found the following manual https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/wiki/UserGuideAdvanced#JPA_monitoring

It contains some info regarding the changes I should make in `persistence.xml` in order to let JavaMelody gather JPA/SQL statistics.

However, it's not quite clear to me, whether should I replace existing `provider` with `JavaMelody`-provider, or should I put it to a separate persistence unit?

I tried the former option, but it broken the application (build failed with the error like 'cannot cast some proxy to EntityManagerFactory').